# Issue with uploading GeoLite2-City.mmdb.missing file in mautic

Tags: geoip, maxmind, mautic

I have a mautic marketing automation installed on my server (I am a beginner)

However i replicated this issue when configuring GeoLite2-City IP lookup

> Automatically fetching the IP lookup data failed. Download http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-City.mmdb.gz, extract if necessary, and upload to /home/ol*****/public_html/mautic4/app/cache/prod/../ip_data/GeoLite2-City.mmdb.

What i attempted

1. i FTP into the `/home/ol****/public_html/mautic4/app/cache/prod/../ip_data/GeoLite2-City.mmdb.` directory
2. uploaded the file (the original GeoLite2-City.mmdb has '0 byte', while the newly added file is about '6000 kb'

However, once i go back into mautic to implement the lookup, the newly added file reverts back to '0byte" and i still cant get the IP lookup configured.

I have also changed the file permission to 0744, but the issue still replicates.

Answer (score 0):

Did you disable the cron job which looks for the file? If not, or if you clicked the button again in the dashboard, it will overwrite the file you manually placed there.

As a side note, the 2.16 release addresses this issue, please take a look at https://www.mautic.org/blog/community/announcing-mautic-2-16/.

Please ensure you take a full backup (files and database) and where possible, run the update at command line to avoid browser timeouts :)